# How to setBadgeText with variable

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In the `background.js` i firstly get a number from different url with `XMLHttpRequest` and `XPath` (this works), than assign the number to a variable (this works too), and than i want pass this number as `BadgeText` and this fails - instead of the number i get only `[object Text]`.

The whole code of `background.js` is:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("GET", "https://app.sistrix.com/app_visindex/__loadModule/lang/de/domain/spiegel.de/source/de/ref/app_controller_efcdc3b3cab713326d8830ac95b499e454ae4e46053a5cc6/_action/_result/_cache//_loadbox/empty/_ajax/1/_module-expire/217287/_controller", true);

xhr.responseType='document';

xhr.send();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  console.log("XHR callback readyState = " + this.readyState);
  if (this.readyState == 4) {

function getElementByXpath(path) {
  return xhr.response.evaluate(path, xhr.response, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
}

console.log( getElementByXpath("//div[@class='data-mini']/span/span[@class='value']/text()") );

    var badgeText = getElementByXpath("//div[@class='data-mini']/span/span[@class='value']/text()");
    console.log( badgeText);
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: String(badgeText)});

console.log( String(badgeText));

  }
}
```

This `console.log( badgeText);` gives the correct number out, but the last `console.log( String(badgeText));` gives `[object Text]` out. Without a `String` before variable `badgeText` i get an error `is not a function`.

How can i pass the number content of the variable into `BadgeText`?

Comment: Should be probably badgeText.innerText, but it's better to use devtools to set breakpoints in the code and inspect the actual values in the Sources panel debugger.

Comment: Alternatively use `stringValue` instead of `singleNodeValue` and STRING_TYPE instead of FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE.

Comment: your second recommendation seem to work:) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `badgeText` variable is a DOM Text object element.

In order to access the text you should use the `data` attribute of `Text`

something like : `badgeText.data` to get the real value.

Here is the documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_text.asp